# undefined result nodejs async await

Tags: node.js, async-await

i'm testing await functions but i have an "undefined" result when i check the return of the async function, my express function is like this (i removed unnecesary code, just to show how i am using the async

```
const getAppsConsumptionSum = async (msisdn, startPeriod, endPeriod) => {
  var urlTigoPlus = 'http://...';
  var args = {
    requestConfig: {
      timeout: config.get('localServer.remoteTimeout')
    }
  };
  remoteApi = await restClient.get(url, args,
    async (data, response) => {
      if (response.statusCode === 200) {
        sumatoria = await group(data.arrayofdata).by('subapplication').reduce(async function(id, entries) {
          return {
            appname: id,
            mb: (entries.map(getBytes).reduce(add)) / 1048576
          };
        });  
        return sumatoria;
      } else  {
        next(utils.error(503));
      }
    }
  );
};
exports.dataAppsConsumption = async function(req, resp, next) {
  let prepaidQuery = 'select ...';
  const resultPrepaid = await clientDseDev.execute(prepaidQuery)
    .then(async resultPrepaid => {
      sumatoria = await getAppsConsumptionSum(variable1, startPeriod, endPeriod);
      console.log('this variable shows undefined ' + sumatoria)

      //i tried also with this
      getAppsConsumptionSum(variable1, startPeriod, endPeriod).then((sumatoria) => {
        console.log('this variable shows undefined ' + sumatoria)
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    });
};
```

Comment: `await` only actually waits for an async operation if that function call returns a promise that is linked to the completion of the async option.  It appears that that is not the case for `restClient.get()` since you're passing it a completion callback.  Thus, your code won't `await` that result.  Plus, you can't `await` inside a callback who's caller isn't expecting a promise to be returned either.  So, your `await` inside that callback won't do what you want either.

Comment: Don't mix regular callbacks and promises.  Convert all async operations to use promises and then and only then can you use async/await simply.

Comment: thanks @jfriend00 so the fix should be using a rest client that supports promises?

Comment: That would be a start.  You will also have to learn how `async` functions return a promise that is fulfilled with their return value and how `await` requires a promise to wait on in order to use them properly.

Comment: You need to return something from `getAppsConsumptionSum` to get something from `await getAppsConsumptionSum(variable1, startPeriod, endPeriod)`

Comment: thanks @ponury-kostek that function returns the variable sumatoria

Answer (score 0):

thanks all for your help, @jfriend00 solution was right, also i had to add a return before the call to the axios function

```
 return axios.get(url, options
 )
 .then(async function (response) {        
    if (response.status === 200){


           group(response.data.arrayofdata).by('subapplication').reduce(function(id, entries) {
            return {
                appname: id,
                mb: (entries.map(getBytes).reduce(add)) / 1048576
            };
        });   

        return sumatoria;
```